# "Data connections" in azure

Tags: azure-sql-database, connection-string, azure-web-app-service

I have a question about "Data connections" in azure.

I have an App Service. I published my API app there. In my app I have connection strings (I need to work with databases). Among numerous settings for my app I saw a "Data connections" item: [image]

There you can add new connection (server, login, password). After creation you can look at connection string for this connection: [image]

My questions are:
 1. what does it do? (I mean in my app I already have a connection string in Web.config and is there any advantages of using connection string in azure?)
 2. how to use this "connection from azure" in my app?

I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you add a **Data Connection**, you can find that it is configured to [**Connection strings** section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-configure) under Application settings blade. And for .NET apps, these connection strings are injected into your .NET configuration connectionStrings settings at runtime, overriding existing entries where the key equals the linked database name.

[image]

Besides, you can find **Data Connection** section is under **Mobile** tab, when we [do with Azure Mobile Apps’ Easy Tables](https://blog.xamarin.com/getting-started-azure-mobile-apps-easy-tables/), we need Data Connection to connect to a database.

Answer (score 2):

Data connections help you create a SQL database in azure and then helps you add the necessary connection string so that you can use it form your app.

If you already have a database/connection string, you can ignore this.

Comment: You don't need to use Data Connections workflow at all if you hit issues, All the workflow does it validate and add the connection string to list of connectionString on the AppSettings. Just add the connection string directly in the App Settings. The Data connections is a helper