# Azure web app service with python script

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-web-app-service

I am completely new to Azure. I have a python Script that does few operations and give me a output.

I have an azure connection that i would like to connect to blob storage from python script which upload and read files.

1) I created a app service where i changed few settings like python3.4 to use
2) created a blob storage account with container.
3) I connected the blob storage to my app service using "data connection" from mobile option.

I now want to write a python that will upload a file and reads it from the blob to process. I came across [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45921301/data-connections-in-azure), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49467961/python-script-to-use-data-from-azure-storage-blob-by-stream-and-update-blob-by)

I am wondering where i can write my python script to connect to blob and read. All I am seeing is just connecting to github, one drive, dropbox. Is there a way i write python script inside azure? I tried reading the documentation of Azure. All it says is connecting to github or use Azure SDK python which is not clear to me.

I saw Azure console where i learned to pip install packages. Where can i open a python env , write code and run it and test?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend checking out this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python

It shows how to Upload, download, and list blobs using Python (in your case you will list then download the blobs for processing):

**Listing blobs:**

```
   # List the blobs in the container
print("\nList blobs in the container")
    generator = block_blob_service.list_blobs(container_name)
    for blob in generator:
        print("\t Blob name: " + blob.name)
```

**Downloading:**

```
    # Download the blob(s).
# Add '_DOWNLOADED' as prefix to '.txt' so you can see both files in Documents.
full_path_to_file2 = os.path.join(local_path, string.replace(local_file_name ,'.txt', '_DOWNLOADED.txt'))
print("\nDownloading blob to " + full_path_to_file2)
block_blob_service.get_blob_to_path(container_name, local_file_name, full_path_to_file2)
```

I can suggest using **Logic Apps** with the blob connectors, more details can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azureblobstorage
You can use triggers (actions) to perform specific  tasks with blobs.